# How to configure skip record in CsvHelper.Configuration if all non-optional fields are empty

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I use CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap to read csv. I use an Optional and validation delegate.

How i can skip row if all his non Optional in map fields is empty?

ClassMap

```
Map(m => m.Col1).Index(0).Name("Column 1").Optional();
Map(m => m.Col2).Index(0).Name("Column 1").Validate(field => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Field));
Map(m => m.Col3).Index(0).Name("Column 1").Validate(field => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Field));
```

CSV:

Col1 Col2 Col3

1   NULL NULL, where "NULL" - is empty

And in deligate "ShouldSkipRecord" have only String[] with raw string of current row.
The order of fields in the file may differ from the index in the map, and I can't get properies of fields by index.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you would need to put in a request for Josh to add more data to the `ShouldSkipRecord` argument so you could check for which fields are required.  This is not a perfect solution because it skips if *any* of the required fields is empty, but it might work for your needs.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        ReadingExceptionOccurred = args => 
        {
            if (args.Exception is CsvHelper.FieldValidationException)
                return false;
            
            return true;            
        }
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Col1,Col2,Col3\n1,,\n2,one,three\n3,,four"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        records.Dump();
    }   
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Col1).Optional();
        Map(m => m.Col2).Validate(field => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Field));
        Map(m => m.Col3).Validate(field => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Field));
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
    public string Col3 { get; set; }
}
```